# on keyup validation is working but on keypress its not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Input box requires following validations:

1) Length input box should take upto 3 integer length values (decimals not allowed)

2) Height input box should take 3 integer number and decimals upto 2 places Its working fine for the first time, but after clicking + button(near of Open New Row  1) same input fields are opening but now: In the new boxes validations are not working even if I use the same classes for input boxes, i.e, newly added input boxes are taking any number of digits and characters.

In keyup function it is working,but if user presses any key it doesn't work for newly opened row, so how to make its working on keypress also in both the cases; on keyup validation is working but on keypress its not working

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
 var inputQuantity = [];
    $(function() {
      $(".form-control").each(function(i) {
        inputQuantity[i]=this.defaultValue;
         $(this).data("idx",i); // save this field's index to access later
      });
      $(".form-control").on("keyup", function (e) {
        var $field = $(this),
            val=this.value,
            $thisIndex=parseInt($field.data("idx"),10); // retrieve the index
//        window.console && console.log($field.is(":invalid"));
          //  $field.is(":invalid") is for Safari, it must be the last to not error in IE8
        if (this.validity && this.validity.badInput || isNaN(val) || $field.is(":invalid") ) {
            this.value = inputQuantity[$thisIndex];
            return;
        } 
        if (val.length > Number($field.attr("maxlength"))) {
          val=val.slice(0, 5);
          $field.val(val);
        }
        inputQuantity[$thisIndex]=val;
      });      
    });
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 0, b2 : 0}];
     $scope.areas = [{id : 'choice2', total : 0}];

     $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
          var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({
               'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo, l2 : 0, b2 : 0
          });
     };
     $scope.removeChoice = function () {
          var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          if (lastItem !== 0) {
               $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
          }
     };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="newscript.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
               <div  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bottom-line no-gap">
                              <h6>Open New Row {{$index + 1}} 
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-right-gap  btn-red" aria-label="Left Align"  ng-click="addNewChoice()" style="margin-top: -5px;" id="plus_icon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                   </button>

                              </h6> 
                              <div class="row walls top-gap">

                                   <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="length">Length :</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="length"  ng-model="choice.l2"  min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.00">
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="height">Height :</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="height"   ng-model="choice.b2"  min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.01">
                                   </div>
                                 
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-red" aria-label="Left Align"  ng-click="removeChoice()" id="minus_icon">
                                   </button>
                              </div>

                         </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fire **keyup** event for all fields we need to change the listener's definition slightly,the selector `.form-control` should be defined inside the `on()` as a child selector & `document` as main selector:

```
$(document).on("keyup",".form-control", function (e) {
// listener code
});
```

**keypress** event behaves differently than **keyup** event. **keypress** is fired for each key pressed & just before the value is set in the field.Whereas **keyup** event is fired for each key released & just after the value is set in the field.So the same approach will not work for **keypress**.

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
 var inputQuantity = [];
    $(function() {
      $(".form-control").each(function (i) {
            inputQuantity[i] = this.defaultValue;
            $(this).data("idx", i); // save this field's index to access later
        });
        $(document).on("keypress", ".form-control", function (e) {
            if (e.charCode!=0){
            var $field = $(this),
            val = this.value + '' + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode), pattern;
            if (this.step == 0.00)
                pattern = /[^0-9]/
            else
                pattern = /[^0-9.]/
            if (val > parseInt(this.max, 10) || pattern.test(val) || (val.match(/\./) && (val.match(/\./g).length > 1 || val.replace(/\d+\./, '').length > 2))) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
           }
        });
        $(document).on("keyup",".form-control", function (e) {
            var $field = $(this),
                val=this.value,
                $thisIndex=parseInt($field.data("idx"),10); 
            if (parseInt(val,10) > parseInt(this.max, 10) ) {
                this.value = inputQuantity[$thisIndex];
                return;
            } 
            if (val.length > Number($field.attr("maxlength"))) {
                val=val.slice(0, 5);
                $field.val(val);
            }
            inputQuantity[$thisIndex]=val;
        });      
    });
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 0, b2 : 0}];
     $scope.areas = [{id : 'choice2', total : 0}];

     $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
          var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({
               'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo, l2 : 0, b2 : 0
          });
     };
     $scope.removeChoice = function () {
          var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          if (lastItem !== 0) {
               $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
          }
     };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="newscript.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
               <div  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bottom-line no-gap">
                              <h6>Open New Row {{$index + 1}} 
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-right-gap  btn-red" aria-label="Left Align"  ng-click="addNewChoice()" style="margin-top: -5px;" id="plus_icon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                   </button>

                              </h6> 
                              <div class="row walls top-gap">

                                   <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="length">Length :</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-red bold" id="length"  ng-model="choice.l2" min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.00">
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="height">Height :</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-red bold" id="height"   ng-model="choice.b2" min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.01">
                                   </div>
                                 
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-red" aria-label="Left Align" ng-click="removeChoice()" id="minus_icon">
                                   </button>
                              </div>

                         </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its fine ,is any way to do the same with on key press,if we removed the on keyup also its ok ,but for while user enter the value it must take.

Comment: ,Yes,because then only user will enter the proper value

Comment: As  per your code i replace the keyup with keypress,but certain scenario its not working,please  if possible give some solution?

Comment: it grate help!!! but after entering 3 integer value in height box,its not taking any decimal value,it must take 2 decimal value,so any idea how to allow this to take decimal value also.

Comment: i am using chrome browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110469/discussion-between-ankit-chaudhary-and-raj). What value are you trying to enter? Is it more than 999?